# How can I plot multiple lines on the same graph in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to analyse data from 5 excel files on Python (repetitions of a same test). I created a for loop to: read each file, perform the necessary operations, plot column 3 ("DMS1 %") versus column 6 ("Stress MPa"). I would like to obtain, at the end of my for loop, a single figure with all lines on the same plot, one for each file. However, when running my code, 5 different plots are created.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
import functions
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\Users\Test Python')
for count,file in enumerate(path.glob('*DMS.csv')):
    print(file)
    # obtain file

    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3])

    # obtain correct diameter and calculate area

    diameter_wb = xl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Diameters.xlsx')
    sheet = diameter_wb['Sheet1']
    diameter = sheet.cell(count+2, 2).value
    area_tendon = functions.area(diameter)   # calculate are of tendon

    # calculate stress

    df["Stress MPa"] = functions.stress(area_tendon, df.iloc[:]['Kraft kN'])

    # calculate Modulus of elasticity (for DMS)

    df['Modulus of Elasticity MPa'] = df.iloc[:]['Stress MPa']/df.iloc[:]['DMS1 %']*10**-2

    df.plot("DMS1 %", "Stress MPa")

plt.show()
```

"DMS1 %" is a column present in the original excel file. "Stress MPa" is a column created in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If, at each iteration of the loop, you store in the dataframe the column that needs to be rendered.

```
columns = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4', 'column_5']
df_visual = pd.DataFrame()
for count, file in enumerate(path.glob('*DMS.csv')):
    ...
    df_visual[columns[count]] = ...
```

Then to plot several lines on one chart, you can use:

```
df_visual.plot.line('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4', 'column_5')
plt.show()
```